# Remove sepecific elememt from Priority Queue of Pair

Tags: java, priority-queue

```
PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>> p = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b)->a.getValue()-b.getValue());
```

This is how the Priority Queue is defined, in which you can see that the elements are sorted according to the value and not the key, in the key-value pair.
Now I want to remove a specific element (not on top of queue), using the key as a seach factor.
Say the Queue has elements ->

```
p.add(new Pair<>(2,1));
p.add(new Pair<>(3,4));
p.add(new Pair<>(1,5);
```

I want to delete the element (3,4), using the key (3);

The expected Output after Deletion should be ->
[[2,1], [1,5]]

Comment: If class `Pair` is a class that you wrote, then did you override its `equals` method? Did you try method [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)).

```java
p.removeIf(x -> x.getKey() == 3);
// removes all elements with key equal to 3
```

Comment: Is `getKey` a method in class `Pair`?

Comment: @Abra I assumed that it exists because of the `getValue` used in the question.

Comment: @Abra yes the Pair class provides a build-in method of getKey() and getValue(), it doesn't give any errors.